# How does one determine the version of rhino distributed with JRE6?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Specfically 1.6.0.14 for Linux

You can use the Rhino context to get the implementation version but the Rhino context is not available when using the JSR-223 spec made available by the Java API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [programming guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) says:

> Sun's implementation of JDK 6 is co-bundled with the Mozilla Rhino based JavaScript script engine. This is based on Mozilla Rhino version 1.6R2. Most of the Rhino implementation is included.

It then proceeds to outline some of the differences between "pure" Rhino and Sun's bundled version.